# endpointscfg get an error google.appengine.ext

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to create end point lib with this command

```
python lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py get_client_lib java -bs src.service.mobile_api.MobileApi
```

but geting this error

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
ImportError: No module named appengine.ext
```

Comment: on [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/get-started-frameworks-python) it mentions that you need a app engine service, have you confirmed that the app engine module name is correct?

Also how are you deploying your endpoint and from where are you deploying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

downlaod

```
 google-cloud-sdk
 https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-versioned-archives
```

it this folder in Document directory then

cd Document/google-cloud-sdk and run this command

```
./install.sh
```

after

```
gcloud components install app-engine-python
```

and update your lib directory with this command in your project like this

```
 cd /project/

 ls

 lib src etc 

 sudo pip install -t lib google-endpoints
```